# Delete 200k+ documents from ElasticSearch using Delete By Query

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch 6.2 - I have approximately 216,000 documents I need to delete from one of our ElasticSearch indexes.  I have a document number for every one of the documents I need to delete.

I have only ever deleted by single document as such:

```
DELETE: http://{{elasticip}}:9200/{{index}}/_doc/101
```

How can I accomplish deleting all 216,000 documents at once, given that I know all 216,000 values for the `_id` field of the documents?

I have used `update_by_query` in ElasticSearch before and I see there is in fact a `delete_by_query` function available as well, but I've never attempted it.  So let's say the documents I need to delete are id's 1,2,3,4,5, and assuming the call looks like this:

```
POST http://{{elasticip}}:9200/{{index}}/_delete_by_query
```

how would the body look?

EDIT 1:
Per answer from @nitzien, I have tried the following two calls:

```
POST http://{{elasticip}}:9200/{{index}}/_delete_by_query

{
    "query": {
        "ids" : {
            "type" : "_doc",
            "values" : ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        }
    }
}
```

AND

```
POST http://{{elasticip}}:9200/{{index}}/_delete_by_query

{
    "query": {
        "ids" : {
            "type" : "_id",
            "values" : ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        }
    }
}
```

However, in both cases, I get `"deleted": 0"` in the response.

I have confirmed that these 5 ids definitely exist in the index, and I can successfully delete them using a `DELETE` statement, one-by-one.

EDIT 2 - problem solved - my doc type in this index is not `_doc` it's `_ssldoc` therefore that had to be updated in the query that @nitzien provided.  Marked nitzien's answer as answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) to delete ids. Please remember to take a backup of elasticsearch index or snapshot before doing this. :)

Comment: Note that you'll probably need to do it in several batches as you will not be allowed to use the `ids` query with 216K ids in it.

Comment: @nitzien - by following your linked page - does this mean I would NOT actually use `delete_by_query` in the call, and rather just do a `DELETE` call?  Or still use `delete_by _query` and use the body syntax that you've linked to?

Comment: Hi @Val thanks for your suggestion - you've always been a great help to me with ES.  Is there is a `batch` function to use in the query, or are you saying I'm going to need to manually separate the 216k records into different groups and run them each manually?

Comment: You'll probably need to batch them yourself.

Comment: You will need to use delete_by_query with body syntax as shown in link.

Comment: Ok, I tried using the exact syntax of the body in the linked article but it returned `"deleted" : 0` in the response.  The field by which I'm identifying my documents to be deleted is `_id` - would I need to change the `type` line to  `"type" : "_id"` ?

Comment: Changing from `"type" : "_doc"` to `"type" : "_id"` still returns zero deletions.

Comment: I'm going to add an edit to my post to update where I'm at.

Comment: Can you please add delete_by_query that you executed? And few sample documents from elasticsearch?

Comment: I figured it out.  My doc type in this index is not `_doc` it's `_ssldoc`.  This is what was missing.  Marking your answer as answer.  Thanks for you help!